# Solving two equations with modified Bessel functions

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions

I am trying to solve two equations with Bessel functions in them,

1)  `C1*BesselK[0, 3.7268*10^-4*x] == 1.3*10^-6`

2)  `x == 53.66*C1*BesselK[1, 3.7268*10^-4*x]`

here `x` and `C1` are unknown constants.

I have tried to solve it with the following expression, but to no use.

```
Solve[{C1*BesselK[0, 3.7268*10^-4*x] == 1.3*10^-6,
       x == 53.66*C1*BesselK[1, 3.7268*10^-4*x]}, {C1, x}]
```

Any suggestions are more than welcome.
Regards

Comment: Thinga like your `3.7268e4` are not the Mma notation. Use `==` instead of `=` in equations. Could you kindly edit your question to pass to the Mma notations, such that one is able to copy-paste it in his notebook?

Comment: Thanks Alexei for your response I have changed it

Answer (score 2):

Your equation is too complicated for `Solve`. You can however try `NSolve` with a range for `x`. I choose here `0<x<1`.

```
NSolve[{C1*BesselK[0, 3.7268*10^-4*x] == 1.3*10^-6, 
 x == 53.66*C1*BesselK[1, 3.7268*10^-4*x], 0 < x < 1}, {C1, x}]
```

> {{C1 -> 1.30002*10^-7, x -> 0.136815}}